# The type ' ' already contains a definition for ' '

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I'm on Unity, trying to make a main menu. Of course, I am super dull and I am very unskilled in coding. However, I love it, but it's just a pain in the ass.

My issue is exactly

> "The type 'LevelManager' already contains a definition for 'OptionsMenu'

I'm just trying to code in an option's button, but it's being a butt. Here's my code;

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;

public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform MainMenu, OptionsMenu;

    public void LoadScene(string name){
        SceneManager.LoadScene(name);
    }
    public void QuitGame(){
        Application.Quit();
    }
    public void OptionsMenu(bool clicked){
        if (clicked == true){
            OptionsMenu.gameObject.SetActive(clicked);
            MainMenu.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        } else {
            OptionsMenu.gameObject.SetActive(clicked);
            MainMenu.gameObject.SetActive(true);            
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a field and a method with the same Name in the same C# class.

```
public Transform MainMenu, OptionsMenu;
```

and

```
public void OptionsMenu(bool clicked)
```

You need to change one of them.

Reason, what if you want to pass the method OptionsMenu to another method:

```
private static void DoSomething(Action<bool> action)
{

}

private static void DoSomething(Transform  t)
{

}
```

Then :

```
var obj = new LevelManager();

// confusing call. Is this the method or the field ?
DoSomething(obj.OptionsMenu);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a transform named `OptionsMenu`  `public Transform OptionsMenu;` then a function named `OptionsMenu`.

Simply rename your `void OptionsMenu(bool clicked)` function or rename the `Transform OptionsMenu` variable.

Comment: Renaming the transform broke it further, but renaming the other piece fixed it. 

Again, sorry for being a bit of a dunce, but it's quite challenging for me to learn this kind of stuff.

Comment: Thank you, by the way. It did help.

Comment: @Activation7X You just have to rename one of them. Is this error now  fixed?